# how to create a table if column names are in one table in a column and data for the column names are in different table in a columns

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have two csv files one has column names of the data and data for those column names are in another csv inside a column of that table. This is the structure of those csv files

| id | unique_ref | money_spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd123 | 120 |
| 2 | bcde234 | 145 |
| 3 | cdef345 | 450 |
| 4 | defg456 | 412 |
| 5 | abcd123 | 127 |
| 6 | bcde234 | 148 |
| 7 | cdef345 | 489 |
| 8 | defg456 | 415 |

| id | fields |
| --- | --- |
| abcd123 | apple |
| bcde234 | orange |
| cdef345 | grape |
| defg456 | watermelon |

Now what I want is to create another CSV which will have these fields as columns and the money_spent as data according to the unique_ref. I can't specify the column name to pivot or transpose because in the real data there are many fields.
I can use SQL or/and Python

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Take a look to Pandas documentation, is a really useful and powerful library to manage dataframes as csv data files.

Comment: If you have 2 CSV file and you want a CSV file, why do you need anything about SQL or databases as part of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over second table's `id`, mask all rows with the same `unique_ref` and make a list of list from that.

```
the_list = [
    [the_row["fields"], data_1[data_1["unique_ref"] == the_row["id"]]["money_spent"].to_numpy().tolist()]
    for index, the_row in data_2.iterrows()
]
```

Now you have a list as:

```
[['abcd123', [120, 127]], ['bcde234', [145, 148]], ['cdef345', [450, 489]], ['defg456', [412, 415]]]
```

Using that you can create a new dataframe:

Please notice you would need the transpose of the data:

```
the_df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(map(list, zip(*[i[1] for i in the_list]))),
    columns=[i[0] for i in the_list]
)
```

The dataframe:

```
   apple  orange  grape  watermelon
0    120     145    450         412
1    127     148    489         415
```

Comment: I used this and was helpful, but in the last part while converting in dataframe it gave me only 1 row. How do I get all the rows?

Comment: I don't know why would that be. That worked for given tables.